# Python function returns only one value

Tags: python, function, nltk

i would like to return from function an array of words generated from nltk.Why this function returns only one word, and if i comment the return and uncomment the print returns the 5 words.

I want to return them, and use them in an other function.

```
    file = open('Text/Walden.txt', 'r',encoding="utf8")
walden = file.read()
walden = walden.split()





def makePairs(arr):
    pairs = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if i < len(arr)-1:
            temp = (arr[i], arr[i+1])
            pairs.append(temp)
    return pairs

def generate(cfd, word = 'the', num = 5):
    for i in range(num):
        arr = []                                      # make an array with the words shown by proper count
        for j in cfd[word]:
            for k in range(cfd[word][j]):
                arr.append(j)

        word = arr[int((len(arr))*random.random())] # choose the word randomly from the conditional distribution
    print(word, end=' ')
    return(word)
            #return random.choices(arr, k=num)


pairs = makePairs(walden)
cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(pairs)
generate(cfd)
```

The output now is like this:

```
little The print The
had 
>>>
```

or

```
But girl?"— print girl?"—
cases 
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `return` statement indented too far.  Back it out one level:

```
def generate(cfd, word = 'the', num = 5):
    for i in range(num):
        arr = []                                      # make an array with the words shown by proper count
        for j in cfd[word]:
            for k in range(cfd[word][j]):
                arr.append(j)
        #print(word, end=' ')
        word = arr[int((len(arr))*random.random())] # choose the word randomly from the conditional distribution

    return(word)
```

When you comment out `return` and use the `print` statement instead, `print` will be called for each iteration in `for i in range(num)...`.  That's why you get 5 print outputs.

Comment: In this line: 'word = arr[int((len(arr))*random.random.... ' i believe you are selecting One Word. The print is before It, so you show all the words

Comment: fernand0, no arguments there.  Seemed like OP was mainly concerned with why `return` wasn't working as expected - I think the `print` statement was mainly for debugging.

Comment: the line `        #print(word, end=' ')` would print whatever is in the variable `word`. Just after it you assing to word a  random position of arr in `word = arr[int((len(arr))*random.random())]` and later you return this. that is, if I'm correct just a word. So my reply explain why this was not working.

Comment: I edit the code, the return is in the same level  of print, it gives error in any other position.

Answer (score 0):

It returns only one word because your `return` statement is within the `for` loop. It's going to go through that first iteration, pick a `word` at random and return it straight away.

This is how I'd fix it - this is also a neat place for `random.choices`:

```
def generate(cfd, word = 'the', num = 5):
    arr = []                  
    for j in cfd[word]: # assuming your code to parse cfd is correct
        for k in range(cfd[word][j]):
            arr.append(j)
    return random.choices(arr, k=num)
```

Comment: it has to make use of the conditional distribution of the makePairs() functions, else it just prints wors, it is not like a phrase.